# UIButton vertical alignment doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uikit

I can't figure why in the following code, the title alignment isn't remain Top.

```
UIButton *btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn2.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:53];
btn2.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 270, 44);
[btn2 setTitle:@"test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn2 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn2.titleLabel.minimumFontSize = 1.0;
btn2.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
btn2.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
btn2.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
```

[image]

Comment: Does the font have to be size 53?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is due to the `baselineAdjustment` default property of the button's `titleLabel`. If you set this to `UIBaselineAdjustmentNone`, you should get the effect you're looking for.

`btn2.titleLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentNone;`

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/baselineAdjustment) for `UILabel`:

> ### baselineAdjustment
>
> Controls how text baselines are adjusted when text
>   needs to shrink to fit in the label.
>
> ```
> @property(nonatomic) UIBaselineAdjustment baselineAdjustment
> ```
>
> #### Discussion
>
> If the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property is set to `YES`, this property controls the behavior of the text baselines in situations where adjustment of the font size is required. The default value of this property is `UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines`. This property is effective only when the `numberOfLines` property is set to `1`.

and

> #### UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines
>
> Adjust text relative to the position of its baseline.
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> #### UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters
>
> Adjust text based relative to the center of its bounding box.
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> #### UIBaselineAdjustmentNone
>
> Adjust text relative to the top-left corner of the bounding box. This is the default adjustment.
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Note that the default adjustment for `UILabel` differs from that of a button's `titleLabel`.

Comment: btn2.titleLabel?.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters

Answer (score 5):

UIButton has a very nifty property named ["`titleEdgeInsets`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleEdgeInsets) which you can use (via [`UIEdgeInsetsMake`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIEdgeInsetsMake) to reposition the top and bottom margins of the title and get the thing centered, vertically.

Comment: yeah, I figured I might use it...but do you have any idea why is this happening?! I mean, wtf.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

***Have a look at Content-Alignment Vertical in storyboard***

Comment: How do you set that programmatically ? I've done that in my views but as soon as I do a tableview reload it resets to vertical center (although not horizontal center...) 

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to get this to work programmatically and just set a baseline constraint to another item. It seems to work great on IB (the content alignment property), even within a Stack View, but in code it does not work.