# UIButton Vertical Align Bottom Not Working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uikit

The `UIButton` title vertical align bottom not working. The button is inside a table cell. I tried several methods.

1. Inside `xib`, select button, on the right panel, click on vertical bottom alignment.
2. Inside `xib`, select button, on the right panel, select title insets and give amount of title inset.

Although in storyboard, I can see the alignment align correctly on bottom of the button, however, when open in **APP**, it **STILL** align centre vertically.

I also try the following code:

```
// change to .alignBaseline still not working. same effect.
questTitleButton.titleLabel?.baselineAdjustment = .none 
questTitleButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
questTitleButton.contentVerticalAlignment = .bottom
questTitleButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

All above method DOES NOT WORK. The button is still vertically centred after running the app.

---

## My Solution

The only way I can make it work is to set a top inset in content insets area.

[image]

Now my question is why? I read many posts, but no one have the same problem as I have.

Such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18304450/2581637), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8503943/2581637). They all have problem with align text but I tried their solutions, only setting content insets works.

So why I can only align text to bottom of button by setting content insets? Did I miss anything here? Did I do something wrong when setting up the button? I use pure autolayout and create the view in `.xib` file.

The button do have a height constraint and there is no constraint conflict or error. Everything seems to be fine.

Comment: Can you please show constraint of your button in inspector?

Answer (score 6):

well, I've just met exactly the same problem. Only x and y constraints were added to the button, and the content held on to its center stubbornly, even though its content has already aligned to bottom showed in storyboard. Finally I figured out a solution, switch to size inspector, and add 1 in content insets' top value, then it all went well.

Comment: Unbelievable, but it still works, May 2023.